# How to set the vee-validate global interaction mode in nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, vee-validate

In a basic nuxt setup, I need to setup the vee-validate `interaction mode` and other settings globally

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file `/plugins/vee-validate.js` and then declare it in `nuxt.config.js` like this:

```
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/vee-validate',
],
```

and there you can add your global settings like this for example:

```
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend, setInteractionMode } from 'vee-validate'
import * as rules from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'

Object.keys(rules).forEach((rule) => {
  extend(rule, rules[rule])
})

extend('password-confirmation', {
  params: ['target'],
  validate(value, { target }) {
    return value === target
  },
  message: "Passwords don't match",
})

extend('password-complexity', {
  getMessage: (field) =>
    `The password must contain at least: 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number, and one special character (E.g. , . _ & ? etc)`,
  validate: (value) => {
    return /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})/.test(value)
  },
})

Vue.component('ValidationObserver', ValidationObserver)
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it-

1. Created a `vee-validate.js` file in my plugins folder like so:

```js
import { extend, setInteractionMode } from 'vee-validate'
import {
  required,
} from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'

extend('required', { ...required, message: 'This field is required' })

setInteractionMode('eager')
```

2. Added it as a plugin to `nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/vee-validate',
]
```